# FluentD to FluentBit with shared key

Tags: input, fluentd, forward

I'm trying to receive data in a Fluent Bit container which is sent from a FluentD container (both running in Openshift), and I'd like to secure this with a shared key: however the container fails to start and complains that the Shared_Key parameter is invalid. Is it possible to do this? If so, how do I specify the shared key? I don't have access to the config file right now: I'll update this post when I do, later on today.